# How to add service reference to WCF service with HTTPS?

Tags: wcf, https

I have a project that works with external WCF service with HTTP. I've added the service using VS2008's "Add Service Reference..." menu option. The address looks as following:

```
http://2.2.2.2:2222/bbbb/BBBB/Name.wsdl
```

I've got the new service address now that looks as following:

```
https://a.b.com/Services/BBBB/Name
```

As you can see there's no .wsdl extension in second address. I'm not sure if that can be the source of some issue.

I'm not able to add the service reference with new address in the same way as I did in case of first address by using "Add Service Reference..." menu option. There's an error.

My question is how can I use the service with new address? Should I keep the old service and change some settings in files obtained through the previous usage of "Add Service Reference..." menu option or something else?

Thank you in advance.

Goran

Answer (score 0):

If you have an arror (what error?) while adding, then you will probably have problems while using (if you change reference files by hand for ex.). You can try menu item "configure service reference" but I think this will not help. Achieve normal "add service reference" completion. Maybe datasvcutil can help (to see more error info)